# wifi doesn't work on ubuntu 16.04 , dell inspiron e5520

Tags: networking, wireless, broadcom

After installing OS update, reboot and wifi doesn't work. Looked at similar problems, but unfortunately there was nothing to help.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

`sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service` doesn't help, driver is worked. property reinstalled.

Comment: Run `sudo modprobe wl` and you'll see the problem. Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: @Pilot6 Tnx i'm searching this problem 1 day. It worked Thank you!!